# Using Q object with variable

Tags: python, django, django-q

I'd like to use the django.db.models.Q object in a way that the query term is coming from a variable.

What i'd like to achieve is identical to this:

```
q = Q(some_field__icontains='sth')
Obj.objects.filter(q)
```

, but the some_field value should come from a variable:

```
field_name='some_field'
q = Q('%s__icontains=sth' % field_name)
Obj.objects.filter(q)
```

, but this solution does not give me the correct result of course.

I also tried to use dictionary this way:

```
dt = {'%s__icontains' % field_name: 'sth'}
q = Q(**dt)
Obj.objects.filter(q)
```

, but this also fails on the result.

How could I use the Q object using variables as query term?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "fails on the result"?

Comment: It does not returns the correct (the expected) number of results. Actually it results 0.

Comment: Are you sure `field_name` is the `some_field` here? If you work with another `field_name`, of course the result can be different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass a 2-tuple to a `Q` object with the name of the fieldname(s) and lookups as first item, and the value as second item:

```
Obj.objects.filter(Q(('%s__icontains' % field_name, 'sth')))
```

this is probably the most convenient way. That being said the dictionary unpacking, although less elegant, should also work.

Comment: Unfortunately the dictionary way does not work, but your solution does! Thanks.

Comment: I am surprised that `Obj.objects.filter(Q(**dt))` didn't work, but why? 

Comment: Unpacking definitely works. Worked for me.